# Angular 2 using templateUrl in @View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to use templateUrl from the @View but it just won't allow it.

If I do it this way it works:

```
import {
    Component,
    View
} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

...But when I try this it breaks:

```
import {
    Component,
    View
} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
})
@View({
   templateUrl: './app/templates/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Is this not allowed? If it's allowed, what I'm I missing?

Comment: `@View` was dropped in beta.10.

Comment: @EricMartinez could you please post the link where its shown that `@view` has been removed ?

Comment: @PardeepJain there it is https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

Comment: I actually prefer it without @View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@View` has been deprecated in latest release, So you can't use it. Only Component is the place that will hold the all options.

Per @Eric's comment, `@View` metadata decorator has been depreacted in `beta.10` release